# Why does Android M not appear in sdk Manager of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sdk-manager

Although I updated android studio to version 1.5 & then updated sdk manager, "Android M(API 22, MNC preview)" still not appear in sdk manager so I couldn't install it.
Sorry if there's any problems in my question form as it's the first time to ask here :)

Comment: Posting the screenshot of SDK manager with expanded list could help us to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Android M(API 22, MNC preview) was preview release of android 6.0. Hance the official stable android 6.0 Marshmallow is released already, Android M(API 22, MNC preview) is now not available in sdk manager. It is replaced by new API23 Android 6.0 Marshmallow. You should use API23 instead of older preview sdk.

[image]

Comment: Aha I got it. Thanks for your answer :)